# Delete Users data from the database based upon ID

Tags: mysql

I have 100 tables in my MYSQL and I use the following query to find all the tables which has the specific Column:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Kiddle_id%';
```

I want to delete the user by passing the `value` of the `Kiddle_id`, so as from users table, i should be able to delete him and from al other tables which has the `Kiddle_id` as column and *verifying its value*, i  should be able to delete his/her contents from other tables

I am confused how do i do it, I do not have cascade option enabled,

Comment: Why don't you have the cascade option enabled? It would be of perfect help in this case.

Comment: can't add it now, the database size is too big and i do not  want to mess up